# Restore vertical buffer position in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have the following code which I use update the coding style on some legacy code I'm working with.  It works okay right now but it's annoying that after the command is executed on a region the buffer scrolls so the top of the region is at the top of the window.  How can I fix this?

```
(defun mkm/cleanup ()
  (interactive)
  (let (start end doit)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq start (region-beginning) end (region-end) doit t)
      (progn (setq start (point-min) end (point-max))
             (setq doit (y-or-n-p "Really cleanup whole buffer? "))))
    (if doit
        (save-excursion
          (save-restriction
            (narrow-to-region start end)
            (replace-regexp "\([[:alpha:]]\)[ ]+" "\1 " nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp " *&" " &" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "[ ]*\\*" " *" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "( +" "(" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp " +)" ")" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "{ +" "{" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "} +" "}" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp " +]" "]" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "\s*,\s*" ", " nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "\s*->\s*" "->" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "\\[ +" "\\[" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp " += +" " = " nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "\([[:alpha:]]\)[ ]+>" "\1>" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "<\s+" "<" nil (point-min) (point-max))
            (replace-regexp "<<\([^\s]\)" "<< \1" nil (point-min) (point-max))))
      (message "Cleanup aborted."))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code, the relevant function is `save-window-excursion`.

```
(defun mkm/cleanup ()
  (interactive)
  (let (start end doit)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq start (region-beginning)
              end (region-end)
              doit t)
      (setq start (point-min)
            end (point-max)
            doit (y-or-n-p "Really cleanup whole buffer? ")))
    (if doit
        (save-window-excursion
          (save-excursion
            (save-restriction
              (narrow-to-region start end)
              (mapc
               (lambda(x)
                 (replace-regexp
                  (car x) (cdr x)
                  nil (point-min) (point-max)))
               '(("\([[:alpha:]]\)[ ]+" . "\1 ")
                 (" *&" . " &")("[ ]*\\*" . " *")
                 ("( +" . "(")(" +)" . ")")("{ +" . "{")
                 ("} +" . "}")(" +]" . "]")("\s*,\s*" . ", ")
                 ("\s*->\s*" . "->")("\\[ +" . "\\[")
                 (" += +" . " = ")
                 ("\([[:alpha:]]\)[ ]+>" . "\1>")
                 ("<\s+" . "<")("<<\([^\s]\)" . "<< \1"))))))
      (message "Cleanup aborted."))))
```

Comment: Great, this worked! I think you mean `save-window-excursion` is the relevant function. And thanks for suggesting the re-factoring, I think it's much nicer this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `save-excursion`?  `save-excursion` says, "Do this stuff, but then return here." It sounds like you want it to instead "Do this stuff, and just stay where you ended up."

Answer (score 0):

You might only need:

```el
(let ((windowstart (window-start)))
  ;; ...
  (set-window-start (selected-window) windowstart))
```